# Timezone in "Date & Time" from gnome control center is frequently wrong

Tags: clock, awesome, date, gnome-control-center

Currently on a system with ubuntu and awesome as the window manager.

For some reason changing the timezone in gnome control center does not do a thing. Running `date` returns the right timezone (as this was modified by appending `TZ='America/Los_Angeles'; export TZ` in .bashrc), but as the clock widget runs by gnome control center's watch, my clock is always set on the wrong (previous) time zone.

I have NTP installed and the time is correct, it's simply that the timezones are not being changed properly.

Answer (score 0):

check and if needed edit `/etc/default/rcS` and change the line `UTC=yes` to `UTC=no`

Comment: what does this do? I changed UTC=yes to UTC=no and changing the timezone still does not actually modify the time.